# Opencart How To] Multi-Store on Xampp Localhost

Tags: xampp, local, opencart

Is there someone that has set up the `Opencart` multistore in their computer locally threw `Xampp` that would know how to add the code properly. I have gone threw as many tutorial as Google and this forum has and can't seem to figure out how to properly place the code. A sample of how it should look when placed in the `http.conf` file will
really help .

The tutorials is asking me to edit the Apache Configuration file add “alias” for each sub store.

Alias `/opcStore_1 "C:/xampp/htdocs/store"`

Alias `/opcStore_2 "C:/xampp/htdocs/store"`

1. go to this path: C:\xampp\apache\conf\
2. Find httppd.conf file and open it
3. *Search ”” section and add below code inside this section*. ???

Alias `/opcStore_1 "C:/xampp/htdocs/store"`

Alias `/opcStore_2 "C:/xampp/htdocs/store"`

**HOW DOES IT LOOKS WHEN THE CODE IS ADDED? Where inside do I add it and how it should look?**
Because I tried placing it but only get error local URL. Thanks

Now, you have to restart Apache server from your `XAMPP` control panel. After restarting, you have to add sub stores in `Opencart` configuration.

`OpenCart` configuration for Multi stores.

1. Logon to your main store : C:/xampp/htdocs/store/admin
2. Goto: System > Settings and here you can add new stores.
3. When adding give stores urls: for First store give url: "http://localhost/opcStore_1/"

for 2nd Store give url: "http://localhost/opcStore_2/"

Answer (score 1):

Will look like this, at the end i have added 5 sub store.

> #
>       # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
>       # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
>       # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
>       # Example:
>       # Redirect permanent /foo http:// localhost/bar
>
> ```
> #
> # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
> # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
> # Example:
> # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
> #
> # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
> # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
> # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
> # the filesystem path.
>
> #
> # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
> # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
> # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
> # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
> # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
> # directives as to Alias.
> #
> ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "cgi-bin/"  Alias /allbridaljewelry "C:/wamp/www/newStore"  Alias /caketopshop "C:/wamp/www/newStore"
> ```
>
> Alias /myspecialparty "C:/wamp/www/newStore"    Alias /superweddingday
>   "C:/wamp/www/newStore"    Alias /weddingfavorsmart
>   "C:/wamp/www/newStore"

Answer (score 0):

You could check this [How to setup our own domain when in a developing stage (not localhost)](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=104&t=56575)/

It is in Indonesian, but you could try translate.google.com to translate this.

Hope it will be a help.

Comment: He need to add in localhost

Answer (score 0):

Let say your main store is `http://localhost/opencart-1.5.6.1`

1. Create your multistore (*store name Malaysia*) and the URL is `http://localhost/opencart-1.5.6.1/malaysia/`
2. Open file C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf and add this code `Alias /opencart-1.5.6.1/malaysia "C:/xampp/htdocs/opencart-1.5.6.1/"` code after `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/xampp/cgi-bin/"`
3. Restart Apache process and try to access this URL `http://localhost/opencart-1.5.6.1/malaysia/`